# Linking error running minimum GTest example

Tags: c++, macos, testing, compiler-errors, googletest

I'm beginning to learn how to use GTest to test a few Cpp and C libraries:

https://github.com/google/googletest

I'm trying out GTest on my macbook, with g++ version

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Homebrew GCC 4.9.4_1) 4.9.4
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

The installation appears successfully, e.g. after `sudo make install`:

```
...
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libgtest.a
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libgtest_main.a
...
```

I've been following this tutorial from a few months ago, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nbFXI9SDfbk

Here is the minimal working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);

    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();

}
```

Here is how it's recommended to be compiled:

```
$ g++ Test.cpp -lgtest -lgtest_main -pthread
```

Above, the libraries are there, and this version of `g++` should have `-pthread` capabilities built in. I get a massive linking error, for reasons I don't understand. Is there an obvious reason why the linking isn't working?

Here's the error, truncated for size:

```
$ g++ Test.cpp -lgtest -lgtest_main -pthread 
/var/folders/1d/_h9qdvds6l5d7x78b21pn1_45n_16x/T//ccYIGdBL.s:7:11: warning: section "__textcoal_nt" is deprecated
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/1d/_h9qdvds6l5d7x78b21pn1_45n_16x/T//ccYIGdBL.s:7:11: note: change section name to "__text"
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::find(char, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      testing::internal::SplitString(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, char, std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > >*) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      testing::internal::FormatDeathTestOutput(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::compare(unsigned long, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      testing::internal::EqFailure(char const*, char const*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, bool) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      testing::GetReservedAttributesForElement(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::ConfigureXmlOutput()     in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      void testing::internal::ParseGoogleTestFlagsOnlyImpl<char>(int*, char**) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      void testing::internal::ParseGoogleTestFlagsOnlyImpl<wchar_t>(int*, wchar_t**) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      testing::internal::InDeathTestChild()     in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      testing::internal::DefaultDeathTestFactory::Create(char const*, testing::internal::RE const*, char const*, int, testing::internal::DeathTest**) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      ...
  "std::__1::__vector_base_common<true>::__throw_length_error() const", referenced from:
      std::__1::vector<testing::TestCase*, std::__1::allocator<testing::TestCase*> >::insert(std::__1::__wrap_iter<testing::TestCase* const*>, testing::TestCase* const&) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > >::allocate(unsigned long) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      void std::__1::vector<char*, std::__1::allocator<char*> >::__push_back_slow_path<char* const>(char* const&) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      std::__1::vector<char*, std::__1::allocator<char*> >::insert(std::__1::__wrap_iter<char* const*>, char* const&) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      void std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > >::__push_back_slow_path<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const>(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >::allocate(unsigned long) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > > >::allocate(unsigned long) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      ...
  "std::__1::__vector_base_common<true>::__throw_out_of_range() const", referenced from:
      std::__1::vector<testing::TestPartResult, std::__1::allocator<testing::TestPartResult> >::at(unsigned long) const in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      std::__1::vector<testing::TestProperty, std::__1::allocator<testing::TestProperty> >::at(unsigned long) const in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
  "std::__1::__basic_string_common<true>::__throw_length_error() const", referenced from:
      __ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE6__initIPKcEENS_9enable_ifIXsr21__is_forward_iteratorIT_EE5valueEvE4typeESA_SA_ in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      __ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE6__initIPcEENS_9enable_ifIXsr21__is_forward_iteratorIT_EE5valueEvE4typeES9_S9_ in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
  "std::__1::locale::use_facet(std::__1::locale::id&) const", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::endl<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
  "std::__1::ios_base::getloc() const", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::endl<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
  "std::logic_error::logic_error(char const*)", referenced from:
      std::__1::map<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, unsigned long, std::__1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const, unsigned long> > >::__construct_node_with_key(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      std::__1::list<std::__1::pair<char, char const*>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<char, char const*> > >::push_back(std::__1::pair<char, char const*> const&) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > >::allocate(unsigned long) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      std::__1::__split_buffer<char*, std::__1::allocator<char*>&>::__split_buffer(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::__1::allocator<char*>&) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      std::__1::__split_buffer<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >&>::__split_buffer(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >&) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >::allocate(unsigned long) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > > >::allocate(unsigned long) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      ...
  "std::runtime_error::runtime_error(char const*)", referenced from:
      testing::internal::GoogleTestFailureException::GoogleTestFailureException(testing::TestPartResult const&) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::erase(unsigned long, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      testing::internal::StripTrailingSpaces(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__init(char const*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      testing::internal::OutputFlagAlsoCheckEnvVar()     in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      testing::internal::FilePath::RemoveDirectoryName() const in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      testing::internal::UnitTestOptions::GetOutputFormat()     in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      testing::internal::UnitTestOptions::GetAbsolutePathToOutputFile()     in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      testing::internal::UnitTestOptions::FilterMatchesTest(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      testing::internal::HasOneFailure(char const*, char const*, char const*, testing::TestPartResultArray const&, testing::TestPartResult::Type, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      testing::internal::String::ShowWideCString(wchar_t const*) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      ...
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__init(char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > std::__1::operator+<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, char const*) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > std::__1::operator+<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(char const*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > std::__1::operator+<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > std::__1::operator+<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, char) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__init(unsigned long, char)", referenced from:
      testing::internal::Indent(int)  in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::append(char const*)", referenced from:
      testing::internal::StringStreamToString(std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      testing::internal::FormatDeathTestOutput(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      testing::AssertionResult::AppendMessage(testing::Message const&) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::append(char const*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > std::__1::operator+<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, char const*) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > std::__1::operator+<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(char const*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > std::__1::operator+<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      testing::internal::FormatDeathTestOutput(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::assign(char const*)", referenced from:
      testing::internal::UnitTestOptions::FilterMatchesTest(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      testing::internal::FilePath::RemoveFileName() const in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::RecordProperty(testing::TestProperty const&) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      testing::internal::FilePath::Normalize()   in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      testing::internal::CapturedStream::CapturedStream(int) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      bool testing::internal::ParseStringFlag<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >(char const*, char const*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::resize(unsigned long, char)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::overflow(int) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::str(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::reserve(unsigned long)", referenced from:
      testing::internal::StringStreamToString(std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      testing::internal::XmlUnitTestResultPrinter::RemoveInvalidXmlCharacters(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::push_back(char)", referenced from:
      testing::internal::StringStreamToString(std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      testing::internal::XmlUnitTestResultPrinter::RemoveInvalidXmlCharacters(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > std::__1::operator+<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, char) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::overflow(int) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      testing::internal::AppendUserMessage(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, testing::Message const&) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      testing::internal::UnitTestOptions::GetAbsolutePathToOutputFile()     in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      testing::internal::SingleFailureChecker::SingleFailureChecker(testing::TestPartResultArray const*, testing::TestPartResult::Type, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      testing::internal::SplitString(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, char, std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > >*) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      testing::AssertionResult::AssertionResult(testing::AssertionResult const&) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      testing::internal::(anonymous namespace)::SplitEscapedString(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      testing::TestInfo::TestInfo(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, char const*, char const*, testing::internal::CodeLocation, void const*, testing::internal::TestFactoryBase*) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      ...
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned long, unsigned long, std::__1::allocator<char> const&)", referenced from:
      testing::internal::SplitString(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, char, std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > >*) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
 ....
  "virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ostream()", referenced from:
      construction vtable for std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >-in-std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
  "virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ostream()", referenced from:
      construction vtable for std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >-in-std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
  "virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_iostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_iostream()", referenced from:
      construction vtable for std::__1::basic_iostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >-in-std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
  "virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_iostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_iostream()", referenced from:
      construction vtable for std::__1::basic_iostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >-in-std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: This works for me on Linux with g++ (GCC) version 6.2.0